# Mirror the scale from the bottom axis to also appear in the top axis

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, teechart

I have a simple 0-100 range of values representing percent using HorizontalBar and the TChart (Embarcadero edition) appears on a ScrollBox in this FMX app because I don't like the panning behavior I've seen in this Delphi 10.3.3 app for Windows.  But the use of the ScrollBox means that sometimes the Bottom Axis is not visible, so I would like to have its Scale repeated as the TopAxis Scale.

Just having the Visible box checked for the Scale of the TopAxis does not produce the desired result.

Currently, I have a crude work-around that uses a separate chart that only exposes its BottomAxis Scale, positioned as a TopAxis Scale in the TChart that shows the data.

Is there a way to specify having the same scale on the bottom and top of one TChart?

Answer (score 1):

On the series set the general option "Horizontal Axis" to Top and Bottom and for  "Vertical Axis" to Left and Right.

[image]